# Solving first order discrete differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a question about solving a first order discrete differential equation. The equation is

$x' = Ax$

with $x_{0} = x0$

I found Runge Kutta could solve the differential equation, but required that $A$ should be a parametric function, like $A(s)$. However, what I have is $A_{s}$, where $A$ is indexed by $s$ and it is discrete. Can anyone help to solve this problem? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already indicated in your question, Runge Kutta works roughly as follows.

We are given the differential equation $x'(t) = A(t)x(t)$ with initial condition $x(0) = x_0.$ Moreover, we are given a constant $h > 0.$ We want to calculate an approximation of $x(h).$ Runge Kutta gives us a "good" approximation of $x(h)$ provided we can calculate $A(0),$ $A(h/2),$ and $A(h).$ Anyone who wants to see a more detailed description of Runge Kutta can look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge_kutta).

Of course, we can iterate this construction and calculate approximations of $x(2h),$ $x(3h),$ $x(4h),\ldots,$ and thus approximate the complete solution of the differential equation. That's what we *really* want. But for the purpose of this question, it's enough to consider just the single step from $x(0)$ to $x(h).$

Now, according to the question, we don't have $A(s)$ for general $s\in \mathbb R,$ but only at a discrete sequence of points. Suppose we are given
$$
A(k\alpha)\qquad for\ a\ fixed\ \alpha\in\mathbb R\ and\ every\ k\in\mathbb N_0.
$$
Then the only way to use Runge Kutta is to put
$$
h = 2\alpha.
$$
In this way, we have $A(s)$ at all the points required by Runge Kutta.

If this doesn't meet your needs, there's a [whole slew of similar methods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Runge%E2%80%93Kutta_methods) which might be helpful in solving your problem.